# global git config changes will not persist

Tags: git, terminal

I try to set my email with `git config --global user.email j.burns@gmx.us` and then when using `git config --global --get user.email` it returns fine, however upon restarting the terminal, or opening a new session it returns the previous entry?

I have tried using `--unset user.email` and it didn't change anything, I have also tried removing the file.

diff for the files

```
$ diff .gitconfig .gitconfig-bak
diff --git a/.gitconfig b/.gitconfig-bak
index 0eb2955..2422c0d 100644
--- a/.gitconfig
+++ b/.gitconfig-bak
@@ -173,4 +173,4 @@

[user]
        name = Josh Burns
        email = jburns@null.netj.burns@gmx.us
```

Comment: There aren't any local-project `.gitconfig` that contains `user.name` and/or `user.email` properties, right? Can you show the contents of `~/.gitconfig` BEFORE and AFTER the `git config --global` commands? (feel free to filter/dummy any sensitive info)

Comment: the only thing that changes is the `user.email` key

Comment: Right, and after you close the terminal, does `~/.gitconfig` still exist? Why would the new config have disappeared? O_o; When does it disappear, exactly? (maybe on closing the terminal, maybe on starting it up, or other)

Comment: My best guess at this point is that you're a guest on some kind of large, shared server that always nukes your personal profile for some weird reason. Or maybe it's a Windows network logon?

Comment: it seems to be created upon starting the terminal, its not a network login its  a personal macbook, no server or anything like that

Comment: That file should persist. There's no normal reason for it to exist exclusively when you have Terminal running. It's a hidden file (files starting with 'dot'), so, if you're using Finder to check its existence, also be sure to show all files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems seems to be within the bash shell itself, removing all of my dotfiles and reinstalling git seemed to have fixed the issue